# GridView dynamic Controls are emptied upon clicking edit/update/delete buttons. Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dynamic, controls, onupdate

I have a gridview that is being dynamically populated using a custom template, but the command fields are static. Upon clicking the command fields, the controls are understandably lost. This problem doesn't affect me during edit, because once the gridview is rebound, it would know it is in edit mode and create the dynamic edit template fields. But once I make changes to these fields, which are textboxes, I would need to click on the Update command field to instantiate my update method. Upon clicking, the controls are immediately lost, so in my update method I cannot find the controls to which changes have been made. Any ideas how to solve this? I will post code if needed.

The Grid View Template. Here is where the databindings happen upon dynamic generation. Getting the data from the table and reproducing it on the grid view works fine.

```
public class GridViewTemplate : System.Web.UI.Control, System.Web.UI.ITemplate
{
    // static attributes here

    // constructor
    public GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType type, string columnName, string categoryID, string itemControl, string editControl, string footerControl, string dataBinds)
    {
        DataRowType = type; // Header, DataRow,
        st_columnName = columnName; // Header name
        st_categoryId = categoryID;
        if (itemControl != null)
            st_itemControl = itemControl.ToUpper(); // Control type for Item Template
        if (editControl != null)
            st_editControl = editControl.ToUpper(); // Control type for Edit Template
        if (footerControl != null)
            st_footerControl = footerControl.ToUpper(); // Control type for Footer Template
        if (dataBinds != null)
            st_dataBinds = dataBinds;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        switch (DataRowType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.Header:
                {
                    // Build the header for this column
                    Label lb_header = new Label();
                    lb_header.Text = "<b>" + st_columnName + "</b>";
                    lb_header.ID = st_categoryId;
                    container.Controls.Add(lb_header);
                }
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(st_categoryId,"^(xxI_)")) // item mode
                    {
                        if (st_itemControl.Equals(LABEL))
                        {
                            // For Label
                        }
                        else if (st_itemControl.Equals(TEXTBOX))
                        {
                            TextBox dcrt_textbox = new TextBox();
                            dcrt_textbox.ID = st_categoryId;
                            dcrt_textbox.Visible = true;
                            dcrt_textbox.Enabled = false;
                            dcrt_textbox.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.TextBox_DataBinding);
                            container.Controls.Add(dcrt_textbox);
                        }
                        else if (st_itemControl.Equals(CHECKBOX))
                        {
                            // For checkbox
                        }

                    }
                    else if (Regex.IsMatch(st_categoryId, "^(xxE_)")) // edit mode
                    {
                        if (st_editControl.Equals(LABEL))
                        {
                            // For label
                        }
                        else if (st_editControl.Equals(TEXTBOX))
                        {
                            TextBox dcrt_textbox = new TextBox();
                            dcrt_textbox.ID = st_categoryId;
                            dcrt_textbox.Visible = true;
                            dcrt_textbox.EnableViewState = true;
                            dcrt_textbox.AutoPostBack = false;
                            dcrt_textbox.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
                            dcrt_textbox.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.TextBox_DataBinding);

                            container.Controls.Add(dcrt_textbox);
                        }
                        else if (st_editControl.Equals(CHECKBOX))
                        {
                            // For checkbox
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow:
                // To be implemented when necessary
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.Pager:
                // To be implemented when necessary
                break;
            case DataControlRowType.Separator:
                // To be implemented when necessary
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void TextBox_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb_databound = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)tb_databound.NamingContainer;
        string RawValue = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, st_columnName).ToString();
        tb_databound.Text = RawValue;
    }

    public void Label_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label lb_databound = (Label)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lb_databound.NamingContainer;
        string RawValue = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, st_columnName).ToString();
        lb_databound.Text = RawValue;
    }

    public void CheckBox_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox cb_databound = (CheckBox)sender; // get the control that raised this event
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)cb_databound.NamingContainer; // get the containing row
        string RawValue = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, st_columnName).ToString();

        if (RawValue.ToUpper().Equals("TRUE"))
        {
            cb_databound.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cb_databound.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The onEdit and onUpdate methods.

```
protected void onRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        tableBind(ViewState["table"]); // View state contains the table, which is then passed to a bind method that binds the gridview.

    }
protected void onRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gv_rebateTable.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        // at this point, xxE_tier (a textbox in edit mode) was destroyed
        TextBox tb = row.FindControl("xxE_tier") as TextBox;

    }
```

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" OnRowEditing="onRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="onRowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="onRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="onRowDeleting" EnableModelValidation="true" ShowFooter="true" OnRowCommand="onRowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
    <Columns>  
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Analysis" ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="" ShowHeader="True"  /> 
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Edit" ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True" ValidationGroup="Edit_Group"/>
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Delete" ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />    
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Definitely show the relevant parts of your code.  That's the best way to get good answers here.  And do your best to distill it down to just what's necessary.  Creating a small example that repeats the problem is a good way to go.

Comment: Show your GridView markup and relevant code.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas please? Or at least some clue to how a regular gridview manages to keep the new values upon going into the onRowUpdating handler?